# issue with php mail function

Tags: php, html

I am writing a PHP script for taking data from HTML form and send it to a specific email. but getting errors shown in pictures. how to resolve it? [image] [image] [image]

Comment: I guess you need to use uppercase: `$_POST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $_POST instead of $_post.

for more details please check below reference site.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php